# Need quick help: IIS 7.5 displaying SWF as text/html in browser?

Tags: flash, iis-7.5

Our IIS 7.5 is displaying .swf files as text/html in browser. This happens only when directly loading the swf in the browser. When it is embedded in a .html file the swf gets displayed fine.

Whats up with that? I *think* it never did that. The correct .swf MIME type is set correctly in IIS. 100% sure.

Edit: I just disabled compression just to make sure. Didn't help. Here is the response header. What the hell?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 25 May 2011 20:46:56 GMT
Content-Length: 20859
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was some sort of problem with the .NET Framework/App Pool. I changed the app pool to classic and it works now. Swfs are beeing delivered correctly. I have no idea why. Not exactly a good solution but in this case it will work

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you being trapped by some rewrite / redirection rule? Using Fiddler, is the content being returned correctly but assuming the wrong mime-type?

Comment: We are not using any rewrite/redir rules. In Fiddler the returned content is correct, it even detects it as a flash, but the mime type is just plain wrong as text/html

Comment: Is it happening with any specific browser? I made a quick research about this topic and found something related to Firefox issues.

Comment: No the problem is in every browser, e.g. FF, IE, Chrome